# Django Admin: Trocar formato de exibição de um campo date

Tags: django

No *Admin*, minha aplicação mostra a data por extenso *19 de janeiro de 2017* na *changed_listview*. Como faço para mostrar a data no forma `DD/MM/AAAA`?

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de fazer isso seria usando o seguinte no seu `settings.py`:

```
from django.conf.locale.pt_BR import formats as br_formats
br_formats.DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
```

É dentro desse arquivo que você vai encontrar como formatar os formatos de data. Pra depois sacar melhor, dá uma olhada no código nesse [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/pt_BR/formats.py).