# Django datetimefield como text

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou criando uma aplicação no django onde terei um formulário para criação de agendamento de consultas, meu model está assim:

```
class Agenda(models.Model):
"""Criação da agenda de consultas da Clinica"""
data_consulta = models.DateTimeField()
paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
servico = models.ForeignKey(Servico, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
observacoes = models.TextField()
status = models.ForeignKey(StatusConsulta, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
form_pagamento = models.ForeignKey(FormPagamento, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
consulta_realizada = models.BooleanField()
data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.servico.servico

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Agenda"
```

Criei uma classe AgendaForm para para gerar o formulário:

```
class AgendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Agenda
    fields = ['paciente', 'servico', 'data_consulta', 'observacoes', 'status', 'form_pagamento']
    labels = {'paciente': 'Paciente', 'servico': 'Serviço',
              'observacoes': 'Observações', 'status': 'Status', 'form_pagamento': 'Forma de Pagamento'}
```

Já no meu views.py tenho o método que irá retornar a minha view:

```
def novoAgendamento(request):
"""Cadastra novos agendamentos"""
if request.method != 'POST':
    form = AgendaForm
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'core/cadastraConsulta.html', context)
```

e por último a minha view:

```html
       {% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Agenda Consulta</h1>
<form action="{% url 'core:novoAgendamento' %}" method="post">
    <table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button>Salvar</button>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

E o django gera o formulário pra mim, o problema é que o campo data da consulta ao invés de mostrar um campo do tipo datetime mostra um campo do tipo text

```
<input type="text" name="data_consulta" id="id_data_consulta" required />
```

Alguém sabe o que preciso mudar para que o campo saia com o formato correto? Lembrando que no django admin funciona normalmente do jeito que preciso.

Comment: Pelo seu código não vejo o porque do erro. Poderia postar seu código no gist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por padrão, o `forms.DateTimeField` vai usar o widget [`DateTimeInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateTimeInput) que tem como `input_type` 'text'. Uma maneira de resolver isso, seria assim:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class AgendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agenda
        widgets = {
            'data_consulta': DateInput()
        }
```

[Referência para o código acima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846048/django-form-as-p-datefield-not-showing-input-type-as-date)

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu! Só precisei alterar meu código no django porque o HTML trás um T entre o dia e hora. mas deu boa, valeu!!

Comment: @CesarVinicius dá uma olhada nesse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251042/django-admin-trocar-formato-de-exibi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-campo-date/251511#251511) sobre como alterar a exibição da data. Talvez também ajude nesse caso